# What does the colloquial "b" mean? Is it a gangland expression?

Tags: etymology, slang

If you watch *The Wire*, you'll notice that Stringer calls Avon "B" quite often.

What does it mean? Is it short for "buddy"? When and where did people start using this expression?

Comment: Obviously, he's the Avon **B**ard.

Comment: Note that Avon's last name is Barksdale—so you have a confluence of _B_ in the sense of blood/brother/b-boy and _B_ as a last-name initial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least some chance that *b* originated as a truncation of *b-boy*, for which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers the following entry:

> **B-boy** *n* {*b* prob. fr. *b*reak (solo instrumental passage) or *b*reak beat} (1981) **:** a male who  engages in the pursuit of hip-hop culture or adopts its styles

According to J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1993), *b-boy* started out with a narrower meaning:

> **b-boy** *n.* {*b*reak dance + *boy*; modeled on *B-girl* [where the *b* originally stood for *bar*]} a male break dancer or (*broadly* and now *usu.*) aficionado of rap music.

Another possibility is that it derives from the slang term *blood* (as in "blood brother" or "person of my blood"). Geneva Smitherman, *Black Talk* (1994) has this entry for *B*:

> **B** 1) A form of address for a male or female, though more common for males; probably a shortened form of BLOOD [which Smitherman defines as "A generic term for any person of African descent; a positive term noting the genetic kinship and shared bloodlines of African people"]. "Yo, B, whassup?" Sometimes the initial for the person's first name is substituted for "B." 2) Euphemism for BITCH.

Oddly, Smitherman doesn't include *b-boy* in her glossary of terms at all. Tom Dalzell, *Flappers 2 Rappers: American Youth Slang* (1996), in a chapter on hip-hop and rap slang, offers a lengthy list of terms used to greet someone:

> "Hello" might be expressed as **Ayo**, **Eh G**, **Give it up**, **Hayo**, **S'up**, **Wassup?** **Wassup, Money?** or **Yo**. Male terms of address include **ace**, **B**, **B-boy**, **blood**, **bro**, **brotha**, **brother**, **cat**, **cuz**, **dog**, **dude**, **G**, **homeboy**, **homepeep**, **home slice**, **homes**, **homey**, **hops**, **jack**, **loc**, **low**, ...

Whether *b* in its current slang sense originated from *b-boy* or from *blood*, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the association of *b* with *bro[ther]* in the sense of close friend or comrade contributed to the popularity of the emerging one-letter slang term.

Answer (score 1):

Being  a slang and probably  recent expression traditional dictionaries are not very helpful, I add below information that may be   helpful in understanding its usage and where is may come from:

***[B](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=b)*** from UD:

> - A greeting to one of your homies
>
>   - *What up B what been goin on*

***[B](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091004221724AA6lQMn):***

> - They say that in New York & New Jersey places in that region its one of them words that you can say to any & everybody like where I'm from everybody says "Bro" like "What's up bro?", "I'll see yall later bro", "Call me when you get this message bro" it's basically the same thing but instead of "Bro" he's saying "B".

(Yahoo.answers)